# AWS RDS Aurora - Update table with subquery is very slow

Tags: mysql, subquery, amazon-aurora

Currently, I have two tables Customers and Orders. The Customer table is more of a report table where I want to insert the first and last order of a customer in the store. The related field is the email column which has an index and the filtering column "store" also has an index. So when I run the following query:

```
update Customer a
set 
a.first_order_id = (select min(c.order_id) from Orders c
     where store = "somename"
       and c.email = a.email);
```

The Customer table has 7k records and the Orders have 7million. The issue is that this query takes forever to finish. The explain query result is:

```
1 - select type: update, type: index, key: primary, rows 6992, filtered: 100
2 - select type: dependent subquery, type: ref, key: orders_email_store, rows: 3 million
```

So I am guessing this is doing a 6992 x 3millions operation. How can I improve the performance?

The only solution I found is to use a stored procedure with a loop, which makes the subquery much faster.

I also tried to do an inner join on the update but the condition to get the minimum order id is my problem.

Any suggestions? Maybe my SQL is just bad.

Answer (score 0):

`c` needs a composite `INDEX(store, email, order_id)`, in that order.

Also, it might be better to use a "multi-table Update" instead of a subquery.

If you need further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; we need to verify that engines, datatypes, etc are not causing trouble.

Separate indexes for each column is *not* the same as a composite index.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I will give it a try with the multiple columns index in case it improves. By the way, what is a `multi-table update`.

Comment: @jameslimousin - see the second syntax on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html